# Inverse of $A + kB$

Tags: linear-algebra

A and B are 3 $\times$ 3 matrices with entries from integers such that $A + kB $ is invertible $\forall k \in \{1,2,...,2018\} $ with inverses also having integer entries. Prove that $A + 2019B $ is also invertible with the inverse having integer entries.

Comment: Hello, and wellcome to math.stackexchange. Can you explain what you've been trying sofar and where you got stuck? This way, you'll be more likely to get help.

Comment: What is your try ??

Comment: I tried finding those inverses in terms of A and B. Tried to write the equations out and see if they could be solved further but no luck. I can see that since the inverses also have integer entries, they belong to $GL_3(Z) , $ multiplicative group. I'm trying to express A + 2019B as a product now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\det(A+xB)$. Then $f$ is a cubic polynomial. Since an integer matrix with integer inverse has determinant $\pm1$, we have $f(k)=\pm1$ for $ k=1,2,\dots,2018$. Since this happens for more than $6$ values of $k$, we conclude that $f$ is constant, because a non-constant cubic function takes any given value at most three times.

Comment: thank you, that's a beautiful answer,